How do I fix token 2022
I have tried to update the spl token 2022 metadata that is held on-chain for token 4EuTCyCpmaHNqxbJJuDdGCGX8TYDHCJx7gpEFYayL7UZ. My linux metadata commands only update the metadata pointer and not the on-chain data (which seems to be corrupted because the token is not acting right please see the screenshots). The token displays correctly in many of the explorers, but some do not display the information correctly, and there is no "market cap" showing on the explorers (there was a market cap for about two weeks and then that information suddenly disappeared and now solana.fm shows an inflated price of 97 million, which is not right. Please see solana.fm I was unable to load the screenshot here) and there is no price shown in various wallets (the token price never did show up) and solscan.io shows unusual data when I search through its webpage (please see solscan.io I was unable to load the screenshot here) and I go to the bottom, using the metadata tab it displays properly, but then I click the "PURPLE TAB" to "view uri metadata" it shows a corrupted form of the metadata. Any help is appreciated.
